# SWFObject relative path

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

Whatever I try I couldn't make this swf file work.
if I put all the files into my root everything works perfectly fine.

Here is my path format;

root: where my index.php located.

inside the root, I have a folder called "public".

inside "public" I have another folder called "_carousel_flash".
This is the place where my swf file is located.
I also have "js" folder located in this directory.

Here is the html code I'm using for adding the swf file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<title>Galleria - Inspire Creativity</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/_carousel_flash/js/swfobject.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/_carousel_flash /js/swfaddress.uncompressed.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="contents">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("public/_carousel_flash/block_slider.swf", "movie", "100%", "100%", "8", "#ffffff");
so.addParam("quality", "high");
so.addParam("id", "movie");
so.addParam("allowFullscreen", "true");
so.write("contents");
so.addParam("salign", "t");
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<title>Galleria - Inspire Creativity</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/_carousel_flash/js/swfobject.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/_carousel_flash /js/swfaddress.uncompressed.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="contents">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("public/_carousel_flash/block_slider.swf", "movie", "100%", "100%", "8", "#ffffff");
so.addParam("quality", "high");
so.addParam("id", "movie");
so.addParam("allowFullscreen", "true");
so.write("contents");
so.addParam("salign", "t");
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**PUBLIC** spell mistake

Comment: it originally spelled correctly. I made a copy paste error when putting it in here. so it's "public" and still not working.

Comment: Why don't you try using an embed and an object elements?

Answer (score 0):

Or else i guess `<script>` tag is causing some issues, try embedding your swf object file

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure what's causing your error, but here are some things I notice about your code:

You're using SWFObject 1.x, which is very outdated and uses different syntax than SWFObject 2.x.  Do you have the correct swfobject.js file for SWFObject 1.x? This is a fairly common issue for SWFObject users.

In SWFObject 1.x, you can't `addParam` after the `so.write` statement... it will not be reflected in your page.

```
so.write("contents");
so.addParam("salign", "t");
```

should be

```
so.addParam("salign", "t");
so.write("contents");
```

You have a typo in the URL for SWFAddress (a space just before "/js/").

If you want to be sure your SWF is located in the root, try loading it directly in the browser using the absolute URL.

Speaking of absolute URLs, it's often helpful to try them in your SWFObject code, too.  Your current URL is file-relative; I suggest either using a site-relative URL (`"/foldername/filename.swf"`) or an absolute URL (`"http://yourdomain.com/foldername/filename.swf"`).